# Ошибка с запросом к MySql | C#

Tags: c#, mysql

Возникла проблема. Я пытаюсь выполнить запрос к бд:

```
dataCommand2.CommandText = "SELECT `Колво` FROM `Товары` WHERE `Название` = '" + textBox1.Text + "'";
string kol = dataCommand2.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

Если в БД есть значение с названием, то все работает, если нет, выдаёт ошибку

> "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта."

Я понимаю, что в БД значения нет, но как тогда обработать null?

Использую MySql.dll

Comment: А если в бд будут 2 продукта с одинаковым названием? Мне кажется, `ExecuteScalar` тут не уместен, надо считывать строки. Ну и использовать параметризованные запросы.

Comment: Не разбираясь с "кривизной" самого запроса (там уже tym32167 уже все сказал) и используя "палиативную медицину" - try {...} catch() спрячет проблему :)

Comment: Он мне её и показывает @АлександрМуксимов

Comment: `dataCommand2.ExecuteScalar()?.ToString();` - как вариант. Если записи нет, executeScalar возвращает null

Comment: Сейчас попробую

Comment: `dataCommand2.ExecuteScalar()?.ToString() ?? ""`